# Deleting rowns based on column value does not work

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to delete some values from my dataframe with the command below:

```
df_merge = df_merge[df_merge['Exchange'] != 'false']
```

or

```
df_merge = df_merge[df_merge['Exchange'] != 'false']
```

I want to exclude all the rows that contain `"false"` in the column `Exchange`. Furthermore, I have used a similar code before to delete other rows, and it worked. I have no idea why it is not working now. The code runs, but no row is deleted, even though I have many rows with the value `"false"`.

I have tried to replace "false" for 0 and that worked. I do not know why, though.

Sample of df:

| index | price | exchange |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | true |
| 2 | 15 | false |
| 3 | 17 | true |
| 4 | 30 | false |

All the columns are "object" type.

Comment: Be careful.  Do they contain the boolean value `False`, or do they contain the string `"false"`?  Those are two very different and incompatible things.

Comment: Can we have the sample of your dateframe?

Comment: It contains "false" as object type.

Comment: I just added a sample.